# What is difference between private and public claims on jwt

Tags: authentication, jwt, claims

What is difference between private and public claims on jwt?

I'm confused with the difference between those two claims. From what I understand they are both custom claims. So what is the difference?

Answer (score 15):

### Public claims

Custom claim names that are required to be collision resistant. Their names should be UUIDs or prefixed by a URL to create a safe namespace for them and avoid collisions.

### Private claims

Custom claim names that are not required to be collision resistant.

> What is difference between private and public claims on jwt?

Only difference is public claims are required to be universally collision resistant while private claims are not.

Comment: thanks for the reply. How do you set a public claim and private claim?

Comment: Since JWT payload is a JSON, technically you can put any key/value pair as claim in there and sign it. Any non-registered claim's name/key that complies to public claim rules is a public claim, otherwise its a private claim.

Comment: Could you please provide an example to make it more straightforward?

Answer (score 1):

Public claims are like public API that defined for public consumption. They should be well documented. [RFC7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1) defines several ways to do it.

1. You can register public claim name in the public IANA "JSON Web Token Claims" registry specified in RFC. There is whole process of approval around it. See [section 10.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-10.1) https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-10.1
2. You have to make sure that public claim name is collision-resistant, i.e. are highly unlikely to collide with other names. Examples are [UUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122), [OID](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3061.txt) or [Domain names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035)

Private claims are claims that are known only to the producer and consumer of a JWT. Private claim names are not collision-resistant and should be used with clear understanding of this and care...