# JWT Public Claim vs JWT Private Claim

Tags: jwt

I'm confused about JWT Claims

From the [link](https://jwt.io/introduction), I found out

### Public Claims

These can be defined at will by those using JWTs. But to avoid collisions they should be defined in the IANA JSON Web Token Registry or be defined as a URI that contains a collision resistant namespace.

### Private Claims

These are the custom claims created to share information between parties that agree on using them and are neither registered or public claims.

#### Another stackoverflow question I found

[Public Claim vs Private Claim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215866/what-is-difference-between-private-and-public-claims-on-jwt)

From these links, what i understood is that public claim cares about collision while private claim doesn't.

So why use private claim instead of public claim?

If private claim doesn't care about collision isn't it always better to use public claim?